# mysql query for same table category and subcategory with separated

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, categories

This question already asked but that not solve my issue.

I have a table given below table name `categories`. I want to fetch all the category with separated `>`. `Parent category` data and `Sub category` data in same table.

```
categoryId   categoryName      categorytype  parentCategoryId   status
1            parent category       0              0                1
2            Sub category          1              1                1
```

[image]

So I want to fetch the data like this
Output:

```
categoryId   categoryName                           categorytype  parentCategoryId   status
    1        parent category                           0              0                1
    2        parent category > Sub category            1              1                1
```

> Only Sub category I want to add parent category as mentioned above.

I tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM categories c1 LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON c2.categoryId = c1.parentCategoryId;
```

Current output:
[image]

Please help me to solve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query joins are OK, selecting right columns will do.

```
SELECT c1.categoryId, CONCAT((CASE WHEN c2.categoryId IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(c2.categoryName, ' > ') ELSE '' END), c1.categoryName) categoryName, c1.categoryType, c1.parentCategoryId, c1.status 
FROM categories c1 
LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON c2.categoryId = c1.parentCategoryId
```

It assumes your category structure is parent-sub two levels only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is working perfectly